# My Facebook object is empty

Tags: php, facebook

I have very simple PHP code from Facebook tutorial:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxx..',
  'secret' => 'xxx...', 
));
```

when I test the `$facebook` object, I see that it hasn't any properties.

I have included the Facebook PHP file. Otherwise it should throw an error. So linking libraries is not my problem.

I have checked `appId` and secret codes and they are correct too. I don't know why facebook object is ampty and it doesn't displays any error.

I am using the newest version of PHP SDK. I updated it just today. I am using the same application to log in the user by Javascript Facebook SDK, so I think, my application is set correctly.

Comment: It works perfectly for me. Are you in the correct namespace? Maybe you can try new \Facebook(...);

Answer (score 0):

Seems perfectly allright..
Add some more code to check and see whether its working and querying the API. Here are some additions that u should add and check to see it its working.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
include_once 'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'=>'******',
'secret'=>'*****',
'cookie'=>true
));

$session=$facebook->getSession();
$me= null;
try
{
$userId=$facebook->getUser();
$me=$facebook->api('/me');
echo $me['first_name'] . " " . $me['last_name'];

}
catch (FacebookApiException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Make sure you add the "try catch" in any of your facebook API code.. Itll show you the error if it encounters any.

If youve got ANY more questions or u feel i didnt answer your question properly, feel free to comment and ill get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if you got the settings to show errors sometimes they need to be explicitly declare like this:

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Answer (score 0):

As I find out, I haven't an empty Facebook object. I am using `Krumo` class to print the object content and it is probably set not to display protectec attributes. When I use the PHP print_r function, I get this object:

> ```
> Facebook Object (
>   [appId:protected] => xxx
>   [apiSecret:protected] => xxx
>   [user:protected] =>
>   [signedRequest:protected] =>
>   [state:protected] =>
>   [accessToken:protected] =>
>   [fileUploadSupport:protected] =>
> )
> ```